# Как определить началась ли новая строка в textarea ? с помощью JQ

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день, мне нужно увеличивать rows  в textarea и увеличивать высоту самого блока вверх, если началась новая строка (как в Skype).
Можно ли проверить началась ли новая строка  с помощью JQ? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Можно решить "в лоб". Берем длинну блока textarea и текущий шрифт. Рассчитываем кол-во символов (k), которые поместятся в строку и делим имеющееся кол-во символов на k. Если число больше 1,2,3 и т.п. , то значит есть переход на новую строку (соответсвенно добавляется 1 2 3 и больше rows). Но есть свойство rows ,которое в js можно получить как  `textarea.rows` и сделать +1 для всех значений выше 1. Вот тут почитать (некоторые атрибуты html5 only) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

Comment: Плагин http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ делает похожую штуку. Можно им воспользоваться, можно посмотреть [код на Гитхабе](https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/blob/master/src/autosize.js).

Comment: Дело в том, что получается разное количества букв (Z ~ 65; z ~ 80), так что такой вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Может быть кому пригодится: проверяю area.scrollTop(), если он вырос тогда увеличиваю rows и размер самого блока. 
Всем спасибо

Comment: Я только хотел про это написать, ну ладно )

Comment: Необычное решение - проверять появился ли скрол=) Но согласен) Кстати - пометь свой ответ как "ответ на вопрос". Это галочка рядом <---"